# Show Drowdown items while using overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I've used `overflow: hidden` to make my layout fluid. Please see (following code) the top right button named `Dropdown Menu`. This is what needs to be fixed.

Please see the following code for reference.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
body {
  font: 14px/18px Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.dropdown-box {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-box:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.overlay-block {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.position-center {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.profile-header {
  display: block;
}
.profile-cover {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.profile-header-content {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: -72px;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-header-content:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.profile-user-image,
.profile-user-video {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-user-image:hover .overlay-block,
.profile-user-video:hover .overlay-block {
  display: block;
}
.profile-user-image:active .overlay-block,
.profile-user-video:active .overlay-block {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}
.profile-user-image img,
.profile-user-video img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.profile-center-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-cover">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="profile-header-content">
    <a class="profile-user-image float-left" href="javascript:;">
      <div class="overlay-block">
        <div class="position-center">Overlay</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="profile-user-video float-right" href="javascript:;">
      <div class="overlay-block">
        <div class="position-center">Overlay</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="profile-center-content">
      <div class="float-left">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="float-right">
        <div class="dropdown-box">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle-dropdown">Dropdown Menu</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot spot a question.

Comment: @cannexo I want to show the dropdown menu. I know overflow will not show the menu. need alternative of overflow, so that the layout will not disturb.

Comment: remove `position: absolute;` from `.dropdown-menu`

Answer (score 0):

when you are using `position: absolute;` the element goes out of the scope. so remove it from `.dropdown-menu` so it stay's in the scope of `profile-center-content` and not considered out of it so it get's scrolled.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
body {
  font: 14px/18px Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.dropdown-box {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-box:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.overlay-block {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.position-center {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.profile-header {
  display: block;
}
.profile-cover {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.profile-header-content {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: -72px;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-header-content:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.profile-user-image,
.profile-user-video {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-user-image:hover .overlay-block,
.profile-user-video:hover .overlay-block {
  display: block;
}
.profile-user-image:active .overlay-block,
.profile-user-video:active .overlay-block {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}
.profile-user-image img,
.profile-user-video img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.profile-center-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-cover">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="profile-header-content">
    <a class="profile-user-image float-left" href="javascript:;">
      <div class="overlay-block">
        <div class="position-center">Overlay</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="profile-user-video float-right" href="javascript:;">
      <div class="overlay-block">
        <div class="position-center">Overlay</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="profile-center-content">
      <div class="float-left">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="float-right">
        <div class="dropdown-box">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle-dropdown">Dropdown Menu</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't you think that the proper way for dropdown is `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @w3debugger Yes.this is how it gets done usually, but in this case removing it solve the problem and do not cause any other as i think.